# Azure Event Hub Python SDK - exceptions

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

If I have 1 throughput unit (which allows 1000 msg/sec or 1Mb/sec) for an Event Hub and try to send more than 1000 msg/sec does the Azure Python SDK throw an exception or have some sort of return code that would notify me that I've exceeded my quota?

Answer (score 1):

There are quotas and limits for Event Hubs(Service Bus).

The number of concurrent connections on a namespace for Event Hubs is 1,000 for NetMessing protocol or 5,000 for AMQP, see below:

[image]

For the message or event size, the entity name limits 50 charaters, and the maximum size of event is 256KB, see below:

[image]

About more details, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-quotas/ to know it.

If you are developing IoT application and the throughput of data exceeds the quota of Event Hubs, I recommend to use the Azure IoT Hub. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-compare-event-hubs/ to know their differences.

Defect is that Azure IoT Hub has SDK for C, .Net, Java, NodeJS currently, but no SDK for Python. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-sdks-summary/ to know IoT SDK, or refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-sdks-summary/ to use the IoT Hub REST APIs.